# Angular 11, Electron 11. Module Not Found for child_process, fs, active-win, sharp, screenshot-desktop

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, electron

I am trying to build my Angular 11 app, that uses Electron 11. I keep on getting build errors. The surprising part is it worked perfectly fine yesterday, but today without making any changes it is giving me build errors. When I try to run it locally, I get the following errors:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'active-win' in '*directory_path*\node_modules\*custom_npm_package_name*\dist\services'

Error: ./node_modules/execa/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '*directory_path*\node_modules\execa'

Error: ./node_modules/execa/node_modules/cross-spawn/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '*directory_path*\node_modules\execa\node_modules\cross-spawn'

Error: ./node_modules/electron/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '*directory_path*\node_modules\electron'

Error: ./node_modules/electron-log/lib/transports/file/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '*directory_path*\node_modules\electron-log\lib\transports\file'

Error: ./node_modules/electron-log/lib/transports/file/findLogPath.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '*directory_path*\node_modules\electron-log\lib\transports\file'

Error: ./node_modules/electron-log/lib/transports/file/getAppName.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '*directory_path*\node_modules\electron-log\lib\transports\file'

Error: ./node_modules/execa/node_modules/cross-spawn/lib/util/readShebang.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '*directory_path*\node_modules\execa\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\util'

Error: ./node_modules/isexe/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '*directory_path*\node_modules\isexe'

Error: ./node_modules/isexe/windows.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '*directory_path*\node_modules\isexe'

Error: ./node_modules/isexe/mode.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '*directory_path*\node_modules\isexe'

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'screenshot-desktop' in '*directory_path*\node_modules\*custom_npm_package_name*\dist\services'

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'sharp' in '*directory_path*\node_modules\*custom_npm_package_name*\dist\services'

Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'
Error from chokidar (C:\node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'
Error from chokidar (C:\node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'
Error from chokidar (C:\node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'
```

My package.json is as follows:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p electron:serve ng:serve",
    "build": "npm run electron:serve-tsc && ng build --base-href ./",
    "build:dev": "npm run build -- -c dev",
    "build:prod": "npm run build -- -c production",
    "ng:serve": "ng serve -c web -o",
    "electron:serve-tsc": "tsc -p tsconfig.serve.json",
    "electron:serve": "wait-on tcp:4200 && npm run electron:serve-tsc && npx electron . --serve",
    "electron:local": "npm run build:prod && npx electron .",
    "electron:build": "npm run build:prod && electron-builder build --publish=never",
    "test": "ng test --watch=false",
    "test:watch": "ng test",
    "e2e": "npm run build:prod && cross-env TS_NODE_PROJECT='e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json' mocha --timeout 300000 --require ts-node/register e2e/**/*.e2e.ts",
    "version": "conventional-changelog -i CHANGELOG.md -s -r 0 && git add CHANGELOG.md",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-material-extensions/fab-menu": "^3.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^9.0.0-beta.31",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@sentry/browser": "^5.18.0",
    "amplitude-js": "^5.9.0",
    "canvas-confetti": "^1.3.2",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "electron-active-window": "0.0.4",
    "electron-log": "3.0.9",
    "electron-prompt": "^1.6.1",
    "electron-store": "^3.3.0",
    "electron-updater": "^4.2.4",
    "http-status-codes": "^1.4.0",
    "is-admin": "^3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "keytar": "^4.13.0",
    "ngx-print": "^1.2.0-beta.5",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
    "tiny-worker": "^2.3.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "tsyringe": "4.4.0",
    "typescript-styleguide-tslint": "^1.1.5",
    "uuid": "^8.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "11.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.1102.0",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "1.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "1.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "1.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "1.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "1.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "11.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "11.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "11.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "11.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "11.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "11.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "11.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "11.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "11.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.6.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.8",
    "@types/mocha": "8.2.0",
    "@types/node": "12.12.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.15.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin-tslint": "4.15.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.15.0",
    "chai": "4.2.0",
    "conventional-changelog-cli": "2.1.1",
    "core-js": "3.6.5",
    "cross-env": "7.0.3",
    "electron": "11.2.0",
    "electron-builder": "22.9.1",
    "electron-reload": "1.5.0",
    "eslint": "7.20.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "31.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.3",
    "jasmine-core": "3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "6.0.0",
    "karma": "6.1.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "3.0.3",
    "karma-electron": "6.3.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.5.4",
    "mocha": "8.2.1",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
    "rxjs": "6.6.3",
    "spectron": "13.0.0",
    "ts-node": "9.1.1",
    "tslib": "2.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.0.5",
    "wait-on": "5.0.1",
    "webdriver-manager": "12.1.8",
    "zone.js": "0.10.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.13.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "chrome 83"
  ]
```

I tried setting:

```
"browser": {
  "child_process": false,
  "fs": false
}
```

in package.json but that doesn't work.
Looking at similar posts on StackOverflow, I also tried adding  `target: "electron-renderer"` inside node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models\webpack-configs\browser.js

Earlier, I got the same error for module `stream, os, path` as well. I was able to rectify those 3 module errors by setting

```
node: {
  stream: true
}
```

inside node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models\webpack-configs\browser.js

However, I am not able to rectify the error for `fs, spark, screenshot-desktop, active-win and child_process`

I also tried deleting the node_modules, package-lock.json, npm cache verify and building again. But it doesn't solve the issue.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.